# Create a line separation for finder in the dock? (osx 10.10)

Tags: finder, macos, dock

I was wondering if it would be possible to create a line separator for the finder app, just like the one found next to the trash can?

[image]

The only behaviour difference that I'd like is for the line to display to the right of the finder app, not left.

I've done a lot of googling with no luck, I can only find a command to create transparent seperations:

Using:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '{ "tile-type" = "spacer-tile"; }'
killall Dock
```

Is anyone aware of how to do this?

Comment: I suppose this cannot be done, because this spacer separates `persistent-apps` from `persistent-others` (can be found in `com.apple.dock` plist).

Answer (score 7):

**Update**: As of December 2022, the project "Vertical Bar" is no longer available on GitHub.

---

I've created a binary release for a project called Vertical Bar that lets you add as many vertical bars as you want to the macOS dock.

Project here:
https://github.com/afallon02/VerticalBar

Comment: I guess in theory this is a work around solution, I guess it's  just a shame I've adopted having the mac bar on the left side of my screen since 2015.  Now all we need is a HorizontalBar ;-)

Comment: It looks pretty nice on bottom dock but for left/right dock this doesn't work at all.

Comment: Protip: rename the VerticalBar-Dark.app file to just a space, so the hover text is blank

Comment: The biggest problem for me with this approach is that the bar is magnified when I hover over it, just like any other icon whereas the separator icon is not magnified.

Answer (score 5):

The dock doesn't support additional horizontal spacers per se (besides those invisible ones), but there used to be a hacky work-around where you made a `.app` file with a line as an icon, and could use that as a spacer.

Basically, create a folder, append .app to it, and give it a separator icon by [changing the icon](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH13922). Then drag and drop the separator to the dock. You can find lots of assets for docks online at sites like deviantart or the old macthemes.net (if that still exists...)

Still, the easiest way is to probably just use the `defaults write` command to get those invisble spacers. I use them and find it works very nicely:

[image: MyDock]

Comment: The biggest problem for me with this approach is that the bar is magnified when I hover over it, just like any other icon whereas the separator icon is not magnified.